# Possible buffer overflow in compat_libevent.c?

Tags: source-code

first of all let me say that I started to study the C three days ago. As exercise I'm reading source code as much as I can. I thought I'd start with Tor and, in this file [`src/common/compat_libevent.c`](https://gitweb.torproject.org/tor.git/tree/src/common/compat_libevent.c), I found something that has puzzled me ([`n = strlcpy(buf, msg, sizeof(buf));`](https://gitweb.torproject.org/tor.git/tree/src/common/compat_libevent.c#n33)):

```
STATIC void
libevent_logging_callback(int severity, const char *msg)
{
  char buf[1024]; //size of buf
  size_t n; //store the maximum size of n
  if (suppress_msg && strstr(msg, suppress_msg)) //if suppress_msg is not NULL and in suppress_msg there is msg...
    return;
  n = strlcpy(buf, msg, sizeof(buf)); //here I'm confused: msg, for example, of 2048 bytes will lead to a buffer overflow... or not?
  if (n && n < sizeof(buf) && buf[n-1] == '\n') {
    buf[n-1] = '\0';
  }
...
```

A `msg`, for example, of 2048 bytes will lead to a buffer overflow, right (or not)?

Comment: There should be no problem, but your concern about coding standarts is a very good point: as for me, I'd use a global define clause like BUFFER_LENGTH and used it as a size specifier, so there would be no such concerns at all.

Comment: Okay but now you have two functions which have buffers of *different length*, and you just specified `BUFFER_LENGTH` as a global variable. That's poor form. Secondly, `sizeof` is a placeholder that is expanded to a constant size at compile time and will *always* be the size of `buf`. There aren't any concerns, this is already better coding practice than your suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The manpage for [`strlcpy()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strlcpy) says:

> The strlcpy() function copies up to size - 1 characters from the NUL-terminated string src to dst, NUL-terminating the result.

So the size in your example is 1024 Bytes (`sizeof(buf)`). As far as I understand it it will copy 1023 from `msg` and terminate with `NUL`. Even if you enter a data block which is larger. So there is no buffer overflow possible. People in https://stackoverflow.com could possibly explain this in more detail.